# Bootstrap - Layout spacing breaks for group of checkboxes when changing visiblity

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following scenario using Bootstrap.

The problem is that when I change the visibility of the first checkbox, it kinda breaks the spacing of the layout.

```
<label for="">Filter</label>
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox"> Filter 1
    </label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox"> Filter 2
    </label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox"> Filter 3
    </label>
</div>
```

You can test [in this CodePen](http://codepen.io/dbugger/pen/wWpaEx?editors=0010) it by clicking on the button.

Did I build badly the HTML? Or am I missing some feature here

Answer (score 0):

The margin-top for .checkbox+.checkbox is set for -5px, this rule applies, regardless of if the first checkbox is visible or not. Better solution would be to add the margin to the text above (which should be no label!) and don't set different margins for the different checkbox-classes.

```
<p>Filter</p>
  <ul  class="checkbox list-unstyled">
  <li> <label> <input type="checkbox"> Filter 1</label> </li>
  <li> <label> <input type="checkbox"> Filter 2</label> </li>
</ul>
```

You would need to change your JS to $(".checkbox li").first().toggleClass('hidden')